# Bash, Cowsay command from file with STDIN

Tags: linux, bash, stdin

I'm still pretty new Linux so I apologize for that. I'm running Fedora, Bash terminal.

I was wondering if there's a way to use STDIN, to print a Cowsay animation to terminal from a file.

For example, if my file is called newfile.txt and the context is:

```
cowsay -f tux "Keep going"
```

What's the correct way to use STDIN to read that command from the file and print it to temrinal?

```
command<newfile.txt
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just do `cowsay < <FILE>`. Example:

```
$ echo aoeu > /tmp/FILE
$ cowsay -f tux < /tmp/FILE
 ______
< aoeu >
 ------
        \   ^__^
         \  (oo)\_______
            (__)\       )\/\
                ||----w |
                ||     ||
```

In `man cowsay` it says:

> If run with no arguments, it accepts standard input

Comment: More generally, if a command doesn't have an option like this, you want `xargs`.

Comment: Because it accepts standard input you can also pipe it in using this construct, which would allow you to use the results from another command:
`$ whoami | cowsay`